# do external javascript on a website objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, web

This is my first post so I am sorry for any mistakes I made :)

I know the title is confusing, but i will try to explain what I want.

I got this website, on the website there is a schedule, this schedule change when you change different values so that it consist with the appropriate person. When you change a value a JavaScript function is called. Is there any way for me to do this JavaScript (on a site I don't own) from objective-C.

So, what I want is this (in a very plain description):

do JavaScript call `change()` on website: "My website" (I know this is not valid, but this is what I want)

Also I would like to be able to change the different values and pass the function with parameters.

Thanks

Kristian

The website is here (Norwegian):

```
http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(mfq2npum0th2lxb0g5oy3045))/design1.aspx?schoolid=60810&code=545354&type=3&id=1559)
```

**Edit:**

Hello I found another way to solve my problem.

The website is automatically generating an image for each of the students. The url of an image is similar to this [link](http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=60810/nb-no&type=3&id=%7B76C567C0-161E-42C3-B054-8941DDD04F52%7D&period=&week=42&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1405&height=683&maxwidth=1405&maxheight=683)

(had some problems posting the URL)

Where you got `&week=42` (you can change this to whatever you want and it works perfect). So I got it working for the MAC (in Safari 5).

But when I try to use this URL in the iPhone simulator I only get a white screen.

this is the code i use:

> [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
>   requestWithURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=60810/nb-no&type=3&id={76C567C0-161E-42C3-B054-8941DDD04F52}&period=&week=42&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=1405&height=683&maxwidth=1405&maxheight=683"]]];

It works if I use a simpler URL like "http://www.google.com" :S Does the iPhone not support for aspx?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do not understand what you want to achieve, and where Objective-C comes into play!

Comment: I think he just wants to call javascript on the web page from his browser... I'm assuming either OSX or from an iphone / ipad.   Incidentally, is Fag really a norwegian name?

Comment: Sam Dufel Yes that is what i want to achieve :) and yes, FAG is norwegian word =P its the word for "class" as in "School Class"

Answer (score 1):

I only know this in the context of iPhone APIs...

Assuming you have the page loaded in a UIWebView inside your app...

You can call `UIWebView` method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to send javascript to the page.

If the calling function returns anything, it will be typecast as a NSString and returned to your app, but in your case it looks like you can just ignore the return value.  You might need to make your Javascript look something like:

```
(function(){
   change();
   return "hello world";
})();
```

because I'm not sure how well it handles void return values.

Comment: Yep this is the method you want, and will execute any JS you provide it.  But you do not to explicitly return a value from the Javascript at all, as it will simply return `nil` if no return ever happens in the JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

let me see if i got it right: i can do javascript on a website through objective-C, for example if i got a function named "hello" on the site i can call that function and my UIWebView will automatically update after doing the javascript. but i don't understand how i would put the "(function(){
   change();
   return "hello world";
})();" inside a program. :/

hope for some more help :)

Comment: NSString* jsToEvaluate = @"change()";
NSString* ret = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jstoEvaluate];